# How to deserialize into a enum variant based on a key name?

Tags: struct, enums, rust, deserialization, serde

I have JSON which takes two forms:

```
"Example:" { "field": 42, "A": 76 }
"Example:" { "field": 42, "B": 110 }
```

I want to deserialize it into a struct like this:

```
struct Example {
    field: i32,
    an_enum: AnEnum,
}
```

where

```
enum AnEnum {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
}
```

I don't know how to do it without writing a custom deserializer for `Example`.

This works:

```
"Example:" { "field": 42, "an_enum": {"A": 76} }
```

or, in YAML:

```
Example:
    field: 42
    an_enum:
        A: 76
```

The `an_enum` is superfluous and annoying to write.  How can I deserialize the first form into the struct? Or, alternatively, how can I declare a struct that will successfully deserialize the syntax I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#flatten):

```
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.104
use serde_json; // 1.0.48

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Example {
    field: i32,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    an_enum: AnEnum,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum AnEnum {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let a = r#"{ "field": 42, "A": 76 }"#;
    let b = r#"{ "field": 42, "B": 110 }"#;

    let a = serde_json::from_str::<Example>(a);
    let b = serde_json::from_str::<Example>(b);

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

```
Ok(Example { field: 42, an_enum: A(76) })
Ok(Example { field: 42, an_enum: B(110) })
```

---

Before this was available, I'd use custom deserialization:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde::de::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Example {
    field: i32,
    an_enum: AnEnum,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum AnEnum {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Example {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
        struct Mapping {
            field: i32,
            #[serde(rename = "A")]
            a: Option<i32>,
            #[serde(rename = "B")]
            b: Option<i32>,
        }

        let Mapping { field, a, b } = Mapping::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        match (a, b) {
            (Some(_), Some(_)) => 
                Err(D::Error::custom("multiple variants specified")),
            (Some(a), None) =>
                Ok(Example { field, an_enum: AnEnum::A(a) }),
            (None, Some(b)) => 
                Ok(Example { field, an_enum: AnEnum::B(b) }),
            (None, None) =>
                Err(D::Error::custom("no variants specified")),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = r#"{ "field": 42, "A": 76 }"#;
    let b = r#"{ "field": 42, "B": 110 }"#;

    let a: Result<Example, _> = serde_json::from_str(a);
    let b: Result<Example, _> = serde_json::from_str(b);

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it with custom deserialization. When I have several variants this code gets tedious, and it happens at least twice in my current task.  What I would like is some sort of annotation on the `an_enum` field to say there will be no tag (or omit it on serialization).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `r#...#` notation. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: It's hard to imagine a derived `Deserialize` implementation to get this right. Basically, this requires the deserializer to discover an enum variant by looking at the various fields and capturing variant names as well as field names. Nevertheless, it might be possible to turn a few parts of this into a macro. Other than that, using multiple options is the least tedious approach, with the down-side of not checking for exclusivity off the bat.

Comment: `#[serde(flatten)]` is exactly what I wanted, thank you.